# How do I get only the time from a Date object?

Tags: javascript, date

I have Date Objects sunrise and sunset, but I only want to call print the time and I am working in Javascript. If I had a date object x is there a better way than to just concatenate the individual values of x.getHours() and x.getMinutes?

Comment: Why do you need a 'better' way - they are not at all expensive operations to undertake. You can simply make a getTime() function, to avoid repetition - something along the lines of getTime = function(myDate){ return myDate.getHours() + ':' + myDate.getMinutes() }; and use it like var time = getTime(addDateHere);

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString

Comment: A better way? Not really, but you could do this `var dt = new Date;
var m = dt.toString().match(/\d+:\d+:\d+/);
console.log(m[0]);`.

Comment: I recommend [Moment JS](https://momentjs.com/) for most complex date-time formatting requirements.